# Can't find Lucene.Net.Spatial.Tier namespace with the current version of Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene.net

In my search for a geolocation search implementation using lucene.net I encountered this [article](http://leapinggorilla.com/Blog/Read/1010/spatial-search-in-lucenenet---worked-example) from leapinggorilla.com and download the source code but have no luck compiling,  I added the reference using nugget but still no luck, and if I browse the assembly using object browser, can't find the Namespace either.

Any suggestions to what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Writer of the LG blog post here! @David Smiley is bang on with his answer. You'll note in the post that we have to pull the 2.9.4.1 version specifically from NuGet to use spatial with .Net

Answer (score 1):

The spatial module in Lucene 3.x was found to be buggy and unmaintained, so it's gone as of Lucene 4.x.  Lucene 4.x has a new spatial module that I developed with 2 others.  If you download it, you should look at the "SpatialExample.java" in the tests (perhaps there's a .net equivalent).  You also might want to watch the presentation I gave at Lucene/Solr Revolution, or simply flip through the slides:
http://www.lucenerevolution.org/2013/Lucene-Solr4-Spatial-Deep-Dive

Answer (score 0):

Lucene.Net is at version 3.0.3 and the 3.x spatial module was dropped from it as well.  The 4.x spatial module was backported from java lucene 4.x.  You can view the source [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net/tree/trunk/src/contrib/Spatial) and the unit tests [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net/tree/trunk/test/contrib/Spatial)

Unfortunately, that means that most of the older blog posts won't work directly with the new API.  However, since most of the API calls should be that same as java's, so I would assume that any blog posts written for java could be translated to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I have a **Lucene.NET 3.0.3 solution which allows spatial search with ordering** (from a centre point), within a circle of a given radius.

The answer is here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674187/41621), and a full VS solution can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/vitamink/lucene-net-examples).

The key portion of code which drives the spatial search is this:

```
var spatialArgs = new SpatialArgs(SpatialOperation.Intersects, searchArea);
var spatialQuery = _strategy.MakeQuery(spatialArgs);
var valueSource = _strategy.MakeRecipDistanceValueSource(searchArea);
var valueSourceFilter = new ValueSourceFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(spatialQuery), valueSource, 0, 1);

var filteredSpatial = new FilteredQuery(query, valueSourceFilter); // Restricts results to searchArea
var spatialRankingQuery = new FunctionQuery(valueSource); // Orders results by distance (closest first)

var bq = new BooleanQuery();
bq.Add(filteredSpatial,Occur.MUST);
bq.Add(spatialRankingQuery,Occur.MUST);
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear. I urge anyone curious to download and examine the full solution.